# Not all CSS elements transferring via parent to child?

Tags: functions, themes, child-theme, css

before I begin I apologize if I have terrible English as it is not my primary language.

I am trying to create a child theme for a website I am working on. The website uses Comicpress theme. I have already created the child and it seems to be working correctly. However I have encountered two issues:

1.) The grey boarder around my post seems to be missing. I am unsure as to why.

2.) I am unable to edit the child's CSS in order to override the parent's.

Can someone please help me out? I will provide the codes I have used and screen shots for comparison. Thank you very much.

---

**PARENT THEME**
[image]
**CHILD THEME**
[image]

**CHILD'S STYLE.CSS**

**CHILD STYLE.CSS**

```
/*
Theme Name: ComicPress-Child
Version: 1.0
Description: A child theme of ComicPress
Template: comicpress
*/
```

**CHILD FUNCTION.PHP**

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style'
        , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/child-style.css'
        , array('parent-style') // declare the dependency
                                // in order to load child-style after parent-style
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

good question! Basically, in your enqueue you call the Parent stylesheet first then the child, so any child styles (by definition of css specificity) will override the parent styles.

Code example from the WordPress codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```